# Python len function on list with embedded sublists and strings

Tags: python

I have a list called movies with two sublists embedded it. Do the sublists have names too? I want to use len() BIF to measure all items in the list and sublists, how do I do that?

Comment: is there any chance that you can add some sample inputs and outputs that you're expecting for them?

Comment: Here my list: movies = ['Lord of the Rings', 'Star Trek', ['Captain Kirk', 'Spok', ['Big Bang', 'Other Movie' ]] ]

Comment: Add your code to show how far you have tried!

Comment: @ChristopherLeone , put the edits in your Question, not just commenting here.

Answer (score 1):

U can use the len() function by specifying the inner sublists

`movies = [  [list1] ,  [list2] ] ;
print(len(movies[0]));  # prints length of 1st sublist 
print(len(movies[1])); #prints length of second sublist`

Answer (score 1):

For the input you've provided, you can recursively find it's length like this :

```
def getLen(l):
    c = 0
    for e in l:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            c += getLen(e) # if the element is a list then recursively find it's length
        else:
            c += 1 # if not simply increase the count
    return c
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
>>> l = ['Lord of the Rings', 'Star Trek', ['Captain Kirk', 'Spok', ['Big Bang', 'Other Movie']]]
>>> getLen(l)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total length of all the sublists, you can try:

```
sum([len(sub) for sub in container_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`:

```
final_length = sum(map(len, data))
```

Comment: wouldn't this be `sum(map(len, data))`?